# Finding a percentage and minus a percentage from it

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a simple line of code that works fine, shown below:

```
If Availability >= DLookup("[Availability]", "[tbl_RAG]", "[Department] = 'Outbound'") Then RAGAvailability.ForeColor = RGB(0, 176, 80) 'green
```

I have modified it slightly to deduct 2% from the figure it finds, shown below (please note the below is the one that's not working:

**Code:**

```
If Availability < DLookup("[Availability]", "[tbl_RAG]", "[Department] = 'Outbound'") - (Format(2, "percent")) Then RAGAvailability.ForeColor = RGB(192, 0, 0) 'red
```

I have also tried:

```
If Availability < DLookup("[Availability]", "[tbl_RAG]", "[Department] = 'Outbound'") - 0.02 Then RAGAvailability.ForeColor = RGB(192, 0, 0) 'red
```

The table TBL_RAG the data is stored as a % already.

Any ideas what I may be doing wrong

Comment: What do you mean with _stored as a %_? What is the actual data type?

Comment: The data type is set to: Number, Double, Percent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second attempt is correct, but perhaps DLookup returns Null? If so:

```
If Availability < Nz(DLookup("[Availability]", "[tbl_RAG]", "[Department] = 'Outbound'"), 0) - 0.02 Then 
    RAGAvailability.ForeColor = RGB(192, 0, 0) 'red
End If
```

or you are using Double and not Currency. Then:

```
If Availability < CCur(Nz(DLookup("[Availability]", "[tbl_RAG]", "[Department] = 'Outbound'"), 0)) - CCur(0.02) Then 
    RAGAvailability.ForeColor = RGB(192, 0, 0) 'red
End If
```

**Edit**:
To change colour back and forth:

```
Dim Color As Long

If Availability < CCur(Nz(DLookup("[Availability]", "[tbl_RAG]", "[Department] = 'Outbound'"), 0)) - CCur(0.02) Then 
    Color = vbRed
Else
    Color = vbBlack
End If
RAGAvailability.ForeColor = Color
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply - Its strange as the label stays red at all times for some reason

Comment: You may have to "reset" the colour. See edit, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use calculus inside your `DLookUp`.

Try the following:

```
If Availability < DLookup("[Availability]-0.02", "[tbl_RAG]", "[Department] = 'Outbound'") Then RAGAvailability.ForeColor = RGB(192, 0, 0) 'red
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply - Its strange as the label strays red at all times for some reason,

Comment: That's something you will have to debug yourself, or you will have to provide enough info for me to do it.

Comment: Thank you for the efforts. I will spend some time working through it. Spent a few hours already, doh!

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for the help. I seem to have corrected the problem using the below code:

```
Dim db As Database, AvailRs As Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Set AvailRs = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from tbl_RAG")

Select Case Availability
    Case Is > Format(AvailRs!UpperAvailability, "percent")
        RAGAvailability.ForeColor = RGB(0, 176, 80)
    Case Is < Format(AvailRs!lowerAvailability, "percent")
        RAGAvailability.ForeColor = RGB(192, 0, 0)
    Case Else
        RAGAvailability.ForeColor = RGB(255, 192, 0)
End Select
```

**What was happening:**
My understanding is the code couldn't read the string from *Available*. I formatted it as percent and put it together using Select Case

Comment: As you will compare strings, that will fail for, say, `"10%" > "2%"`. Use _Currency_ whenever dealing with amounts.

Comment: Thank you for the advice